# USB Drive detection circuit

Tags: arduino, usb, detection, drive

I am building a simple portable speaker using a DFPlayer Mini, but I think that's not entirely relevant to my question.

I am looking for a way to detect when an USB Drive is plugged in, so the player can start reading data from it. I haven't found anything on this issue on the internet, so what i came up with is this circuit:

[image: USB Detection circuit diagram]

I expect the USB to drain enough current to switch on the transistor, so the HIGH IF USB CONNECTED line is driven high. I'm not sure whether the resistor values are appropriate, but I didn't want to waste too much current.

In my mind, this should work, as the USB should be able to work up to as low as 3.3 V.

It just came to my mind that I don't actually need the voltage regulator, but where do I connect the 4.3 V on the Arduino board? To 5V or 3V3?

If you see any other flaws with my design, please let me know.

Comment: This function is taken care of by the hardware and software of a viable USB host implementation - instead of implementing it from scratch, you should be studying the documentation of your host solution.  **However you do not appear to have any USB host in your system at all** therefore your project is likely not realizable.  SD cards which your hardware is made to support in a legacy mode are quite different from USB.

Comment: The DFPlayer actually has a support fot USB drives. But I found nothing on the detection of its presence.

Comment: Given that the letters "USB" appear nowhere in the manual except in an image, it seems that such a capability, if actually present, isn't something they are being very forthcoming about. Nevertheless, if there is something that works, it is overwhelmingly likely that it will not require you to graft on an additional detection scheme.

Comment: this company http://www.yx080.com makes the `YX5200-24SS` control chip in the DFPlayer

Comment: check here https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/mp3-files-on-spi-flash-for-yx5200-24ss-mp3-chip/ .... i think that you can use the USB for connecting to your computer and then manage the files on the SD card using your computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Arduino library](https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/DFPlayer_Mini_SKU:DFR0299) for DFPlayer includes a status for CardInserted and CardRemoved.

I assume they simply poll the USB key for presence.

Just read the code in the link above or at [Github](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobotDFPlayerMini/blob/master/examples/GetStarted/getStarted.ino)

Answer (score 1):

As drawn your circuit does not work. You USB drive needs the 5V power provided to it, unless it has separate power (which you do not show). You could put a shunt resistor along the USB port, as current flows you would have a voltage drop and you could detect if it has been plugged in from a hardware perspective.

I would check the software solution, as the USB stack implements different power up checks with speed detection based on the device pull ups.